# Numpy blockwise reduce operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, reduce

I consider myself an experienced numpy user, but im not able to find a solution for the following problem. Assume there are the following arrays:

```
# sorted array of times
t = numpy.cumsum(numpy.random.random(size = 100))
#  some values associated with the times
x = numpy.random.random(size=100)
# some indices into the time/data array
indices = numpy.cumsum(numpy.random.randint(low = 1, high=10,size = 20)) 
indices = indices[indices <90] # respect size of 100
if len(indices) % 2: # make number of indices even
    indices = indices[:-1]

# select some starting and end indices
istart = indices[0::2]
iend   = indices[1::2]
```

What I now want is to reduce the value array `x` given the intervals denoted by `istart` and `iend`. I.e.

```
# e.g. use max reduce, I'll probably also need mean and stdv
what_i_want = numpy.array([numpy.max(x[is:ie]) for is,ie in zip(istart,iend)])
```

I have already googled a lot but all I could find was blockwise operations via `stride_tricks` which only allows for regular blocks. I was not able to find a solution without performing a pyhthon loop :-(
In my real application arrays are much larger and performance does matter, so i use `numba.jit` for the moment.

Is there any numpy function I'm missing which is able to do that?

Comment: Would `x` always have floating pt numbers in `[0,1)`?

Comment: No. `x` in general is a much more complicated array structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you looked at [`ufunc.reduceat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html)?  With `np.maximum`, you can do something like:

```
>>> np.maximum.reduceat(x, indices)
```

which yields the maximum values along the slices `x[indices[i]:indices[i+1]]`.  To get what you want (`x[indices[2i]:indices[2i+1]`), you could do

```
>>> np.maximum.reduceat(x, indices)[::2]
```

if you don't mind the extra computations of `x[inidices[2i-1]:indices[2i]]`.  This yields the following:

```
>>> numpy.array([numpy.max(x[ib:ie]) for ib,ie in zip(istart,iend)])
array([ 0.60265618,  0.97866485,  0.78869449,  0.79371198,  0.15463711,
        0.72413702,  0.97669218,  0.86605981])

>>> np.maximum.reduceat(x, indices)[::2]
array([ 0.60265618,  0.97866485,  0.78869449,  0.79371198,  0.15463711,
        0.72413702,  0.97669218,  0.86605981])
```

Comment: Awesome, thats exactly what i was looking for. I can just keep all indices in one array, then i dont do any overhead computations :) Maybe i should improve my googling skills...

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)
like this:

```
what_i_want = np.array([np.max(x[np.r_[ib:ie]]) for ib,ie in zip(istart,iend)])
```

Answer (score 0):

(A non-`numpy` solution, using [astropy](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/index.html))

```py
import numpy as np
from astropy.nddata.utils import block_reduce
data = np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4)
block_reduce(data, 2)
```

will convert:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

to:

```
array([[10, 18],
       [42, 50]])
```

See [this](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.nddata.block_reduce.html) for more examples.